# Adding environment variables in container definition of ECS cloudformation property by looping through the environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have defined a task definition as below:

```
Resources:
  ECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: ExampleDef
          Essential: true
          Image: image-reference
          PortMappings:
            - Name: example-80-tcp
              ContainerPort: 80
              HostPort: 80
              Protocol: tcp
              AppProtocol: http
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options: 
              awslogs-create-group: "true"
              awslogs-group: /ecs/example
              awslogs-region: ap-northeast-1
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
          Environment:
              - Name: END_DATE
                Value: "20230903"
              - Name: START_DATE
                Value: "20230901"
              - Name: MODE
                Value: "dev"
```

I want to create a task that runs multiple containers. These containers varies based on their environment variables. The following is an example of environment variables

```
[
    {
        "END_DATE": "20230903",
        "START_DATE": "20230901",
        "MODE": "dev"
    },
    {
        "END_DATE": "20230906",
        "START_DATE": "20230904",
        "MODE": "dev"
    },
    {
        "END_DATE": "20230909",
        "START_DATE": "20230907",
        "MODE": "dev"
    }
]
```

There could be more sets of environment variables, so I want to loop through these environment variables and substitute them in the environment property of the cloudformation template to avoid repeating the code. I have looked at `Fn::ForEach` but faced some issue. Is there anyway to create multiple container from the same task definition in the cloudformation template?

I would also like to know if it is better to create multiple container inside a task, or it would be better to create one task for each container, where the container would differ only by the environment variable?

Comment: "I have looked at Fn::ForEach but faced some issue": what was the issue you had faced? Thank you!

Comment: Did you add the Transform line at the top of the page for the !ForEach?